# Plot Multiple Pandas Dataframes

Tags: python, python-3.x, pandas, dataframe, matplotlib

I am trying to plot multiple pandas dataframes on one graph.

So far I have pretty much achieved this however out of 4 dataframes one of them is not displaying propperly:

This is the code:

```
ax = df1.plot(figsize=(30,10))
df2.plot(ax=ax)
df3.plot(ax=ax)
df4.plot(ax=ax)
```

and here is an example of what I mean with the graph:

[Example Plot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Av8AO.png)

Where am I going wrong?

Comment: So, `df1` has completely different numbers than the others, hence it looks like a straight line. No chance to know if this is expected or not, because the data is unknown.

Comment: Since we do not know what your data looks like we cannot identify the problem.  My guess is everything is working fine and you just don't understand your fourth set of data.  How did you expect it to look?

Comment: Ahh apologies, just looked into the data a bit deeper and you are correct, looks like there is a spurious reading! Thanks!